# How do exceptions during Rhino readFile work?

Tags: rhino

I have this code running inside Rhino under Linux. The file doesn't exist.

```
try {
  var u = readFile("/tmp/wtf");
  print(u);
} catch (e) {
  print("error!");
}
```

1. The code in the 'catch' doesn't run, even though the file definitely isn't there. I just get a blank value assigned to 'u'. Is this normal?
2. Are there other situations (besides a file missing) where the catch *would* run?
3. Could I differentiate an empty file from a missing one without invoking some other function? (I realize Rhino gives me access to most of the standard Java libaries).
4. Just want to confirm that readFile is always synchronous?

I can't find anything much on SO or MDN about how readFile works. Any insight appreciated.